# rails - Finding intersections between multiple arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, array-intersect

I am trying to find the intersection values between multiple arrays.

for example

```
code1 = [1,2,3]
code2 = [2,3,4]
code3 = [0,2,6]
```

So the result would be 2

I know in PHP you can do this with array_intersect

I wanted to be able to easily add additional array so I don't really want to use multiple loops

Any ideas ?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use the [&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26) method of [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) which is for set intersection.

For example:

```
> [1,2,3] & [2,3,4] & [0,2,6]
=> [2]
```

Comment: @Anurag Are you sure this works? Unless I'm misunderstanding OP's requirements, the first and last arrays aren't tested against one-another for intersection. E.g., `[1,2,3] & [4,5,6] & [1,2,3]` returns an empty array.

Comment: @Cyle any element in the result of a three-way intersection should exist in all three operands.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)

Answer (score 57):

If you want a simpler way to do this with an array of arrays of unknown length, you can use inject.

```
> arrays = [code1,code2,code3]
> arrays.inject(:&)                   # Ruby 1.9 shorthand
=> [2]
> arrays.inject{|codes,x| codes & x } # Full syntax works with 1.8 and 1.9
=> [2]
```

Comment: `arrays.inject(:&)` will not work in 1.9. this will work though `arrays.inject(:'&')`

Answer (score 4):

### Array#intersection (Ruby 2.7+)

Ruby 2.7 introduced [Array#intersection](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-intersection) method to match the more succinct [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-26).

So, now, `[1, 2, 3] & [2, 3, 4] & [0, 2, 6]` can be rewritten in a more verbose way, e.g.

```rb
[1, 2, 3].intersection([2, 3, 4]).intersection([0, 2, 6])
# => [2]

[1, 2, 3].intersection([2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 6])
# => [2]
```

Comment: Are both methods the same?

Comment: @Christopher Oezbek, almost.
If you click on "click to toggle source" in the docs you will see that "intersection" is calling "&" under the hood.