# Regular expression to strip everything but words

Tags: ruby, regex, strip, words

I'm helpless on regular expressions so please help me on this problem.

Basically I am downloading web pages and rss feeds and want to strip everything except plain words. No periods, commas, if, ands, and buts. Literally I have a list of the most common words used in English and I also want to strip those too but I think I know how to do that and don't need a regular expression because it would be really way to long.

How do I strip everything from a chunk of text except words that are delimited by spaces? Everything else goes in the trash.

This works quite well thanks to Pavel `.split(/[^[:alpha:]]/).uniq!`

Comment: What about apostrophes (or even greengrocer's apostrophes)?

Comment: nokogriri is probably the best solution here because it is an HTML parser and i guess one shouldn't be using regex to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what fits you best would be splitting of the string into words.  In this case, [`String::split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000803) function would be the better option.  It accepts a regexp that matches substrings, which should *split the source string into array elements*.

In your case, it should be "some non-alphabetic characters".  Alphabetic [character class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes) is denoted by `[:alpha:]`.   So, here's the example of what you need:

```
irb(main):001:0> "asd, < er >w , we., wZr,fq.".split(/[^[:alpha:]]+/)
=> ["asd", "er", "w", "we", "wZr", "fq"]
```

You may further filter the result by [intersecting the resultant array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197412/rails-finding-intersections-between-multiple-arrays) with array that contains only English words:

```
irb(main):001:0> ["asd", "er", "w", "we", "wZr", "fq"] & ["we","you","me"]
=> ["we"]
```

Comment: ok that worked quite will but I'm getting a done of empty strings in the array

Comment: @Sam, perhaps, you could find helpful information in `split` documentation?  It should contain tips about situations, in which empty strings appear.

Comment: if you want to retrieve words of other languages (with characters like 'ä', 'ß', 'ǹ' etc), use this regex in your split call:
    /[^\p{Alpha}]+/

Answer (score 0):

try `\b\w*\b` to match whole words