# How to make a word list from a text file in a more Ruby way?

Tags: ruby, syntax, split

I'd like to get a word list from a text file using Ruby. I found how to use regex to parse only words [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538640/regular-expression-to-strip-everything-but-words), so I made a script like following:

```
src = File.open("text.txt")
word_list = []
src.each do |line|
  word_list << line.downcase.split(/[^[:alpha:]]/).delete_if {|x| x == ""}
end
word_list.flatten!.uniq!.sort!
p word_list
```

And the following is a sample text file `text.txt`:

> TextMate may be the latest craze for developing Ruby on Rails
>   applications, but Vim is forever.  This plugin offers the following
>   features for Ruby on Rails application development.
>
> 1. Automatically detects buffers containing files from Rails applications, and applies settings to those buffers (and only those
>      buffers).  You can use an autocommand to apply your own custom
>      settings as well.
> 2. Unintrusive.  Only files in a Rails application should be affected; regular Ruby scripts are left untouched.  Even when enabled, the
>      plugin should keep out of your way if you're not using its features.
> 3. Easy navigation of the Rails directory structure.  gf considers context and knows about partials, fixtures, and much more.  There are
>      two commands, :A (alternate) and :R (related) for easy jumping between
>      files, including favorites like model to migration, template to
>      helper, and controller to functional test.  For more advanced usage,
>      :Rmodel, :Rview, :Rcontroller, and several other commands are
>      provided.

As a Ruby novice, I'd like to learn better (more clear, concise, and following conventions) solutions for this problem.

Thanks for any advices and corrections.

Comment: Don't you think more clear and concise are contradictory? If you  are a novice, I suggest you spend some time understanding the methods instead of reposting.

Comment: I don't think this is just a repost. What I want to know is more Ruby way to solve this problem, not spliting words using regex.

Comment: What exactly is your question then? I see some code....

Comment: Your input file is missing. Does it include hyphenated words like `word-list`?

Comment: I've changed the tile of this question to express purpose clearly. Also, I added input text file to the question. No hyphenated words in the text file.

Comment: Does these words include the following -   :A , you're   -  IF it does, then your regular expression is wrong.

Comment: ":A" is split by colon, since colon is not an alphabet chararcter. Then I can get "A" as a word element. If I don't want A to be in a list, the regex is wrong as you mentioned. Am I getting it right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12163/discussion-between-subs-and-philipjkim)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more idiomatic code would be:

```
word_list = open("text.txt")
  .lines
  .flat_map { |line| line.downcase.split(/[^[:alpha:]]/).reject(&:empty?) }
  .uniq
  .sort
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# I suppose you want each line and collect the results
word_list = File.open("text.txt").each_line.collect do |line|
   # collecting is done via collect above, no need anymore
   # .reject(&:empty?) calls .empty? on each element
   line.downcase.split(/[^[:alpha:]]/).reject(&:empty?)
# you can chain on blocks as well
end.flatten!.uniq!.sort!

p word_list
```

Comment: I got an error: `undefined method 'each_line' for File:Class (NoMethodError)` Am I doing something wrong? (FYI I use ruby1.9.3)